# How do I take a variable from views.py in Django and display it on my HTML page

Tags: python, html, django, pandas, django-templates

I'm new to Django and need help with views.py. I'm trying to call on a variable from views.py on my HTML template but have no idea how to do so. The following is my views.py function:

```
def scheduleAlgo(request):
    givenData=pd.read_csv('~\OneDrive\Desktop\example.csv')
    df = pd.DataFrame(givenData)
    df['Mean']=df.mean(axis=1)
    df = df.sort_values(by="Mean", ascending=False)
    df.set_index("Subject", inplace = True)
    firstSubject = df.index[0]
    secondSubject = df.index[1]
    thirdSubject = df.index[2]
    fourthSubject = df.index[3]
    fifthSubject = df['Mean'].idxmin()
    if fifthSubject==fourthSubject:
        fourthSubject=df.index[4]
    subjectList=[fifthSubject,fourthSubject,thirdSubject,secondSubject,firstSubject]

    subjectSelection = random.choices(subjectList, weights=(20,18,17,16,15),k=5)
    return render(request, 
    'main/testml.html', 
    {
    'firstItem': subjectSelection[0],
    'secondItem':subjectSelection[1],
    'thirdItem':subjectSelection[2],
    'fourthItem':subjectSelection[3],
    'fifthItem':subjectSelection[4],
    }) #assigning values for calling in template
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ firstItem }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Also, my urls.py:

```
    path("testml", views.scheduleAlgo, name="scheduleAlgo"),
```

I'm quite sure the function itself works since I tested it out on an iPython notebook.
Essentially, I want to be able to call an index from the list (subjectSelection) and display it in my HTML code. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: you don't need to set each item as index of the list, instead you can do a loop in the template itself, check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: @LinhNguyen so what do I write in my context dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently my code was correct but I had assigned two views to a single template. This is incorrect and you have to merge them into a single view in order to correct it.